# JQuery Select box and Dynamic Label

Tags: jquery, dynamic, listbox, row

How can I take data from a populated listbox and create a dropdown and label from that data?

So, I want to pull value and text from a DDL and create a tableRow with a label for each record. I tried using logic below but it did not work.

My idea is:

```
('#box2View option').attr("selected","selected");

$('#box2View :selected').each(function(i, selected) 
        {

     $('#TableGroup').append(createRow(counter, $(selected).val(),$(selected).text()) );

        {
```

here is the DDL:

```
<select id='box2View'>
    <option>one</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option>
</select>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are selecting one box then go for click on `$('#box2View :selected')`.
It's better if you start coding and ask if in doubt on where you're stuck.

Comment: Yeah, I did start coding but I got a little confused and did not want to confuse anyone with a bad approach. I will post what I was working on